# Missing Hibernate in Power Options

Tags: windows, windows-10, hibernate, power-management

Missing **Hibernate** in Power Options on Windows 10

Power Options:
[image: Power Options]

System info:
[image: System info]

What could be a problem?

So I can't check this as in below picture:
[image: screenshot from internet]

**UPDATE**

this helped (in CMD as admin):

```
powercfg /hibernate on
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this helped (in CMD as admin):

```
powercfg /hibernate on
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the drive of your display adapter to enable the Hibernate option within the shutdown button.

Comment: I have display driver installed... and I already added the solution myself